# How to manipulate forms with Mootools

Tags: forms, mootools, request, send

I'm trying to manipulate forms with Mootools. My purpose is to inject the response content of a form into a div element named `result`.

Here a code that works, but it replaces the content of the `result` div. This is not what I want : I want to ADD the form response content to the result div existing content. I just can't find on the web how to do this, and I've tried many things that are not working ... Please help

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {      
  $('myform').addEvent('submit', function(e) {    
    e.stop();     
    var result = $('result').empty();      
    this.set('send',{    
        url: this.get('action'),    
        data: this,    
        onSuccess: function() {    
            result.set("html", this.response.text);    
        }    
    }).send();      
  });      
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only text you want to add, just remove the `empty` method, and replace `result.set()` with `result.appendText()`.

If you need to append an element tree, repeat the first step, and do:

```
onSuccess: function(){
    Elements.from(this.response.text).inject(result);
}
```

Btw. It's all in the documentation - http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I just didn't know we could do `Elements.from`. Very useful thanks !

Comment: Indeed, I use it all the time. It's especially handy in conjunction with `Elements.from('<strong>{greet}</strong> Oskar'.substitute({'greet': 'hello'}));`